Error en Pipeline al ejecutar tarea AzureCLI
En Azure DevOps estoy montando un pipeline que a partir de un repositorio con proyecto para docker (con fichero Docker-Compose) automatiza el compulilado y la publicación del servicio. El caso es que para la siguiente tarea me da un error de ruta:
 - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Docker Build
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          docker build -t service:$(tag).
          docker save service:$(tag) -o service_$(tag).tar


/usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/azureclitaskscript1713529050063.sh
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 2B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2163565617/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
Error response from daemon: reference does not exist

Creo que no lo está buscando en la carpeta correcta pero tampoco se donde lo tiene que buscar ni que que manera. ¿alguna idea?
Esta primera parte del Pipeline es así (error en la tarea AzureCLI@2):
trigger:

master

pool:
vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
variables:
tag: 1.0.0-$(Build.BuildId)
buildConfiguration: 'Release'
acrINT: 'XXXXX'
aKSINT: 'XXXXX'
azureSubscriptionEndpoint: 'XXXXXX'
azureContainerRegistry: 'XXXXX'
dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.yml'
resourceGroupName: ''
clusterName: ''
stages:

stage: Build
displayName: Build
jobs:

job: Build_code
displayName: Build
pool:
vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
steps:

task: UseDotNet@2
displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
inputs:
version: 8.x
performMultiLevelLookup: true
includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions

task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
inputs:
command: 'build'
projects: '**/*.csproj'

task: DockerCompose@0
inputs:
workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
containerregistrytype: 'Azure Container Registry'
azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
azureContainerRegistry: '$(azureContainerRegistry)'
dockerComposeFile: '$(dockerComposeFile)'
additionalDockerComposeFiles: 'docker-compose.override.yml'
dockerComposeFileArgs: 'DOCKER_BUILD_SOURCE='
action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
dockerComposeCommand: 'build --parallel'

task: AzureCLI@2
displayName: Docker Build
inputs:
azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
scriptType: 'bash'
scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
inlineScript: |
docker build -t service:$(tag) .
docker save service:$(tag) -o service_$(tag).tar

task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
inputs:
targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
artifact: 'service-artifact'
publishLocation: 'pipeline'






